# addprovider() method loading before java.security provider methods

Tags: java, security, websphere

i have a code in which we add provider dynamically to java.security and some are available in java.security.
Now, what happens is some times this addprovider() method is called before loading java.security which adds this provider at the top of the array and some times java.security first loads the pre-available methods and then addprovider() is called this adds this provider to last.

can someone suggest how to add this provider always to the last.

Comment: At what phase do you add it today?